# Hibernate Lazy loading vs explicit query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a database performance concern.

Let's suppose my data model looks like follows.

**UserTable.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

// other user fields

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<ProfilePhotoTable> photos = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<AlbumPhotoTable> photos = new HashSet<>();
```

**PhotoTable.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "PHOTO_ID", nullable = false)
private Long photoId;

// other photo fields

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private UserTable user;
```

**ProfilePhotoTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFILEPHOTO")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PROFILEPHOTO_ID", referencedColumnName = "PHOTO_ID")
public class ProfilePhotoTable extends PhotoTable
```

**AlbumPhotoTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALBUMPHOTO")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ALBUMPHOTO_ID", referencedColumnName = "PHOTO_ID")
public class ProfilePhotoTable extends PhotoTable
```

Now let's say I want to write a query that would fetch all the photos for the user - all profile photos and all album photos.

However, I don't want the photos to be fetched every time that I'm requesting the User information from the database, and this is why I specified the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` on the photo fields.

Basically, I have a doubt between the two approaches.

1. Two independent queries, the first one fetching the `UserTable` from the database by the ID, and the second fetching the photos, something like `SELECT * FROM Photo WHERE userId = :userId`.
2. One single query that would `join fetch` the user with the corresponding photos. However, I'm not quite sure how this query would go, since the photos are separated in the Album and Profile photos. I found in this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/) that something like

   comments = entityManager.createQuery(

   "select pc " +
   "from PostComment pc " +
   "join fetch pc.post " +
   "where pc.review = :review", PostComment.class)
   .setParameter("review", review)
   .getResultList();

should be used, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my use-case.

The question is, which approach is better in terms of performance, and if 2nd, how the query should be structured?

Comment: ..you can make the `user` eager (="not lazy") (to achieve what you want (as I understand) ..and "lazyness" makes most sense on the "N:-" side of the association)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using JPA 2.1 or higher you can use **@NamedEntityGraph** to control, if you want to fetch your data "EAGER" or "LAZY".

This article explains it very well: https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer would depend on what fraction of your user queries also query for photos. If the answer is a small fraction, then it would make sense to keep it lazy so that you don't have to pull them all the time. 
I would anyway not store photos in a traditional relational database type of setup. I would put them in some kind of object store and only keep ids back with RDBMS.